# Adding an integer to a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

I have a variable declared here:

```
var quizScore = 0;
```

And I want to add a number to it each time the `correctAnswer()` function runs:

```
function correctAnswer(){
  quizScore+1;
    console.log ( 'correct answer selected: quizscore = ' + quizScore );
}
```

I added a console log for debugging. It works, so the function is being called, but it is not adding the score. Do I need to parse this to an integer? I can't work out what the +1 needs to be to work correctly.

You can go here and you will see that clicking "Lightning Bolt" for question 1 shows "correct answer" in the console, but doesn't add to the score variable.

Comment: it should be `quizScore = quizScore + 1`.  You're not assigning anything when you add.

Comment: well it seems like you are new to js and posting questions along the way you are working on this quiz app, i suggest making a jsfiddle.net  and linking to it from your questions..

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. A valid question with sufficient information and background.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
function correctAnswer(){
    console.log ( 'correct answer selected: quizscore = ' + (++quizScore) );
}
```

You just need to assign the +1 to quizScore variable. This may be the fastest way to add 1 and display it in one line

Answer (score 1):

You're adding one to whatever value is in `quizScore`, and doing nothing with the result.

You need `quizScore = quizScore + 1`.

Comment: or simply `quizScore++`;

Answer (score 1):

Keep quizscore as global variable.
And secondly change the line no.1 of your `correctAnswer()` function to

```
quizScore = quizScore + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use self-memorizing function not to pollute global environment with variables like so:

```
function correctAnswer() {
    correctAnswer.quizScore = (correctAnswer.quizScore || 0) + 1;
    console.log("QuizScore : " + correctAnswer.quizScore);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    correctAnswer(); // output 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
}
```

Comment: Just `correctAnswer.quizScore = (correctAnswer.quizScore || 0) + 1` would suffice

Answer (score 0):

Right now, when you do this:

```
quizscore+1;
```

You add one to it but it doesn't assign the change to the variable. One reason for this is that sometimes you may want to add a number to the variable long enough to perform an operation but you don't want it to change.

```
// quiz score is left alone
var nextscore = quizscore + 1
```

Here are the different ways to actually assign it:

```
// temporarily adds 1 to quizscore, then saves it to quizscore
quizscore = quizscore + 1

// adds one to quizscore after it's used in an expression
quizscore++

// adds one to quizscore before it's used in an expression
++quizscore
```

So if you did something like this:

```
var nextscore = ++quizscore + 1;
```

You would both increment the current score and predict the next score.

Read more: [Expressions and Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)