# Javascript Global Variable won't change

Tags: javascript, variables

I  have the following code in an external JavaScript file:

```
var number = 1;
function doSomething() {
    alert(number);
    number++;
}
```

`doSomething()` is called when a button is clicked.

However, every time the button is clicked the alert message always stays as `1` and `number` is never increased. If I put `number++;` before the alert, the alert displays `2` every time.

I have also tried defining `number` as: `var window.number = 1;` and `window.number = 1;` with no success.

How do I make this actually increment the variable and store it OUTSIDE of the function in `number`?

Comment: Works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/bcEU3/

Comment: See this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412415/adding-an-integer-to-a-javascript-variable/22412622#22412622

Comment: No... I've provided all the code that is running

Comment: It's depending on how `doSomething()` is called: `number` might be out of scope. You could wrap the declaration of `number` and `doSomething()` in a immediatly called closure and export `doSomething()` by assiging it to `window` or attach the event handler directly inside the closure.

Comment: It was as the Quentin said, because I had the function on a submit button, it was refreshing the page after the javascript ran which reset `number` to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the comments on the question, the only explanation that I can think of is that the button is:

- inside a form
- a submit button

When you click it, the JavaScript runs, then the form submits.

The action of the form is, presumably, undefined or `""` so it reloads the page.

This reinitialises the JS and `number` is set back to `1`.

- Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` *or*
- remove the form *or*
- prevent the default action in your JS

Comment: You are correct, and this works.